# How to listen to onKeydown when alert dialog box is open

Tags: android

I have a check box, upon unchecking the box, I show alert dialog. I want to retain the preference when back key is pressed on display of alert dialog pop up.
 I am aware of onKeyDown method and facing problem when I want to use it with alertDialogBuilder. How do I listen to back key/on key down event when there is alert dialog pop up , and retain the checkbox preference when user unchecked>got the pop up>but pressed back key. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, there is no need to use onKeydown instead I can use:setOnCancelListener

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setIcon(
    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info).setTitle(
    R.string.pref_title_mms_notification_led_color).setView(v)
    .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mDialogShowing = false;
            mNotificationManager.cancel(0);
        }
    }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
```